# query based on column value order by in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have the result in the following manner in the DB2. But, I'm looking to pull the details based on a column value which is matching with Y order

```
Name    Ind
----------------
syed    N
syed    Y
syed    N
shaik   Y
shaik   N
shaik   N
```

The output should be like

```
shaik   Y
shaik   N
shaik   N
syed    N
syed    Y
syed    N
```

The name values which are having Y first row as indicator should come as first.

Any ideas

Comment: Describe clearly what you want to see and what the logic is - do not let us guess!

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

This sounds like two keys in an `order by`:

```
order by name, ind desc
```

Your question hints that you might want names with `'Y'` anywhere to be first, suggesting that not all names might have `'Y'`.  If this is the case, you can use window functions in the `order by`:

```
order by max(ind) over (partition by name) desc,  -- names with 'Y's first
         name,
         ind desc
```

Comment: @Gardon, I'm updating my question. My question is little bit different. Apologies

Comment: @Syed . . . It is rude to change a question after it has been answered, particularly in a way that invalidates the answer *and* is incomprehensible.  And, there is no created date in the database unless you have that explicitly in the row.

Comment: I accept and apologies for that Gordon. But, I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @Syed . . . .Apparently, you cannot do what you want, if those are the only columns in the table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets (I see the difference now).  If you don't have a column specifying the ordering, there is no order to the rows.

Comment: So, we can't do anything to get the result? There are other columns as well in the table